# Print syntax error, python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

Wrote some code and this syntax error keeps on occuring but I can't solve it. Due to wanting this only to print when verbose option is on I have included all code relating to the error line.

```
from __future__ import print_function
print = print_function
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true",help="Help option"
verboseprint = print  if verbose else lambda *a, **k: None 

                if line2_rev:
                    verboseprint "Line2 has now been reversed"

    verboseprint " Line2 has now been reversed"
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have attempted using ' ' instead as well as changing the string inside but same error occured. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `from __future__ import print_function`, `print()` is a *function*, not a statement. You cannot use `verboseprint` as a statement either.

Use it as a function instead:

```
from __future__ import print_function

parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true",help="Help option"
verboseprint = print  if verbose else lambda *a, **k: None 

if line2_rev:
    verboseprint("Line2 has now been reversed")
```

The `__future__` import changes the way the compiler works; the `print` keyword is removed from the language for this specific module, and the built-in `print()` *function* which is already present in Python 2 becomes available instead. So instead of:

```
print "This is printed"
```

You'd use:

```
print("This is printed")
```

but in your code you define a new function that'll work the same.

You don't need to assign `print = print_function` either in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `import print_function`, you do not use something named `print_function` but you changed to use Python3 syntax instead of print keyword syntax.

When in Python2 traditionally you would say:

```
print 'something', 'other',
```

You say with  `import from __future__ import print_function`

```
print('Something', 'other', end='')
```